# Unable to Execute Stored Procedure using Hibernate 5.0.8

Tags: hibernate

I m running into an issue of Executing stored procedure in hibernate (5.0.8).
Below is the code for the same ...

MyDao.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List getList() {

    ProcedureCall procedureCall = getSessionFactory()
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createStoredProcedureCall(
                    "mysp_get_stored_proc",
                    MyClass.class);
    procedureCall.registerParameter("p_code_category",String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue("WORLD");
    procedureCall.registerParameter("p_cdt_language", String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue("FRENCH");
    procedureCall.registerParameter("p_lst", Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
    procedureCall.registerParameter("p_err_code_out", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
    procedureCall.registerParameter("p_err_msg_out", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);


    ProcedureOutputs procedureOutputs = procedureCall.getOutputs();
    ResultSetOutput resultSetOutput = (ResultSetOutput) procedureOutputs.getCurrent();
    List list = resultSetOutput.getResultList();

    return list;
}
```

My Stored procedure signature :

```
   PROCEDURE mysp_get_stored_proc (
  p_code_category   IN       code_table.code_cat_cd%TYPE,
  p_cdt_language    IN    object_intr.ct_language_cd%TYPE,
  p_lst                   OUT      ref_cur,
  p_err_code_out          OUT      NUMBER,
  p_err_msg_out          OUT      VARCHAR2
```

)

Error Message :

```
java.sql.SQLException: The number of parameter names does not match the number of registered praremeters
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.setNamedParameters(OracleSql.java:198)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4712)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1376)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:958)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.execute(WSJdbcPre
```

Can somebody help in where and what is wrong .... ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the ref_cursor the correct way. Below is the example how you can use the ref_cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_reviews(bookid bigint)
RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  reviews refcursor;           -- Declare cursor variables                         
BEGIN
  OPEN reviews FOR SELECT id, comment, rating, version, book_id FROM review     WHERE book_id = bookId;
  RETURN reviews;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Named Procedure Query  :

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
name = "getReviews", 
procedureName = "get_reviews", 
resultClasses = Review.class, 
parameters = {
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type =   void.class), 
    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Long.class)
}
)
```

And this is how you can use the query :

```
 List<Book> books = (List<Book>)            this.em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getBooks").getResultList();
  for (Book b : books) {
  StoredProcedureQuery q =    this.em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getReviews");
 q.setParameter(2, b.getId());
 List<Review> reviews = q.getResultList();
 for (Review r : reviews) {
    // do something
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pushpendra ... Eventually The Stored procedure is running fine in SQL developer... Moreover its been used or executed via Standard JDBC CallableStatements .... I was just trying to Run it using Hibernate,,,, You may consider that the SP is running fine .... :)

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined!
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4709)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1376)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:958)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.execute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:625)
 at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:52)
 ... 93 more

Comment: well ordinal binding means binding the parameters on the basis of index and named binding means the parameters on the basis of name. So above error signifies that you are using both of these together.